# Jest API like done() but works with multiple callbacks in asynchronous tests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jestjs

I've test cases in jest which rely on asserting 1 or more callbacks to be called after a setTimeout to test asynchronous nature.
Examples

```js
function publish(eventName, args) {
  const callbacks = getAllCallbacks(eventName);
  // Subscriptions being called asynchronously
  setTimeout(() => {
    callbacks.forEach(cb => {
      callback(...args);
    });
  }, 1000);
}


// Example 1
it('test 1 callback after executed twice', (done) => {
  const callback = jest.fn((arg) => {
    expect(arg).toBe('some value');
    done() // but done should be called after being called the second time
  })
  subscribe('eventName', callback);
  publish('eventName', args); // first publish
  publish('eventName', args); // second publish
  expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2); // but callback will be called after 5 seconds
});


// Example 2
it('test 1 callback after executed twice', (done) => {
  const callback1 = jest.fn((arg) => {
    expect(arg).toBe('some value');
    done() // but done should be called after all callbacks were executed
  })
  const callback2 = jest.fn((arg) => {
    expect(arg).toBe('some value');
    done() // but done should be called after all callbacks were executed
  })
  subscribe('eventName', callback);
  subscribe('eventName', callback2);
  publish('eventName', args);

  expect(callback1).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // but callback will be called after 5 seconds
  expect(callback2).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // but callback will be called after ~1 second
});
```

Above test cases are incorrect because done is not being called after "ALL" callbacks were executed,
and `expect().toHaveBeenCalledTimes()` will also not execute asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches I could use was by creating an HOC.

```
// Helper
function mockCallbacks(_done: any) {
  let count = 0;
  return (callback: any, callCounts = 0) => {
    count = callCounts || count + 1;
    return jest.fn((...args) => {
      callback(...args);
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
      if (--count === 0) {
        _done();
      }
    });
  };
}

// Usage
it('test same callback multiple times', done => {
  const mocker = mockCallbacks(done);

  const callback = mocker((data: any) => {
    expect(data).toBe('something');
  }, 2);
  subscribe('eventName', callback);
  publish('eventName');
  publish('eventName');
});

// OR 
it('test multiple callbacks', done => {
  const mocker = mockCallbacks(done);

  const callback1 = mocker((data: any) => {
    expect(data).toBe('something');
  });
  const callback2 = mocker((data: any) => {
    expect(data).toBe('something');
  });
  
  subscribe('eventName', callback1);
  subscribe('eventName', callback2);
  publish('eventName');
});
```

While it helped solve most use cases, the challenge of waiting for the callbacks to execute assertions after all callbacks are executed still remains. i.e., testing `callback.toHaveBeenCalled()` is still difficult since it get executed before the setTimeout callback.